# CharacterController get stuck near the top of boxes (collider problems?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

---

### (i edit the code NOW IT WORK(with neu jump functin),  the problem seems TO BE the isGrouned() function, but still don't know why my character don't pop grouned)

The character gets stuck when I try to jump closer to a box (and moving into box direction). Some clue what can be happening and how to solve it?

situation:

[image: situation]

It seems character get stuck when the character controller Collider star reducing the radius.

NavMesh information:
[NavMesh information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgBbk.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgBbk.png)
[[image: NavMesh information][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgBbk.png)

character controller:

[image: character controller]

I expected the character reach the top of the box, or atleast he become able to climb that little diference

jump code:

```
 public void jump()
    {

        if (OnSlope())
        {
            print("controller.height: " + controller.height);
            controller.Move(Vector3.down * controller.height / 2 * slopeForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        print("key press jump");

        JumpMode = true;
        StartCoroutine(JumpEvent());

    }

        private IEnumerator JumpEvent()
{
    controller.slopeLimit = 90.0f;
    float timeInAir = 0.0f;
    //print("IEnumerator JumpEvent");

    float timePassed = 0;
    while (timePassed < 1.5F)
    {
        float jumpForce = jumpFallOff.Evaluate(timeInAir);
        controller.Move(Vector3.up * jumpForce * jumpMultiplier * Time.deltaTime);
        timeInAir += Time.deltaTime;
        // Code to go left here
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        yield return null;
    }

    /*
    do
    {
        float jumpForce = jumpFallOff.Evaluate(timeInAir);
        controller.Move(Vector3.up * jumpForce * jumpMultiplier * Time.deltaTime);
        timeInAir += Time.deltaTime;
        //print("INTOWHILE JumpEvent");
        //print("inside- controller.isGrounded: " + controller.isGrounded);
        //print("inside-(controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Below) == 0): " + ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Below) == 0));//.ToString()
        //print("inside-((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Above) == 0) " + ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Above) == 0));
        yield return null;

    }
    while (!controller.isGrounded);// &&  controller.collisionFlags != CollisionFlags.Below);//  .Above); ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Below) == 0) && ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Above) == 0));//
    */


    //print("outside- controller.isGrounded: " + controller.isGrounded);
    //print("outside- (controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Below) == 0): " + ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Below) == 0));//.ToString()
    //print("outside- ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Above) == 0) " + ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Above) == 0));

    controller.slopeLimit = 45.0f;
    JumpMode = false;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a navmesh?

Comment: @BugFinder *yes*

Comment: have you compared the height of the box to the navmesh settings for steps?

Comment: @BugFinder *nothing strange for me. I add some NavMesh information on the post, that might help*

Comment: Your box is 1m tall and you told it that it can climb 0.75.. ergo it doesnt climb on the box

Comment: @BugFinder Since I'm not home now, I will test it later. But I'm trying to reach the box by jumping not walking. I didn't know NavMesh affects player controller

Comment: I havent checked the jump but the controller certainly uses navmesh settings.. as I have had problems with steps in the past.  Jumping, you'd need to slow down time (which you can do) and watch how the collider and the box are interracting as because the collider is a lot wider than his feet.. that will effect what you thought he could do because you as a person could and what he can do because of the collider

Comment: @BugFinder That didn't fix it, i think that 0,75 its the size of stairs that the player can go up. Thanks anyways, if you see some other thing that can be the probleme,do not doubt to tell me!

Answer (score 0):

put in the "Step Ofset" property of the Character Controller a high value(like 10 for example) with this your character will climb thar cube like a stairs.